# seeking a way use non-looping method for calculation in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops

I am porting a c program to matlab for simulation of some mathematical problem. I have all the code rewritten in matlab but I found there spent too much time in one loop. I don't know if there is any better way to calculate the following instead of using a for statement

I have about 1000 matrices (all of the same dimension) defined within a structure

A{1} = matrix1
A{2} = matrix2
...
A{1000} = matrix1000

B is a constant matrix of the same dimension of A{n}

I want to calculate the element-by-element production of A{n} and B and return the total sum of all resulting elements to

```
for k=1:1000
  AllSum(k) = sum(sum(A{k}.*B))
end
```

the size of A depends on the parameter, the typical size is 300x300. If I run the above loop for once, the speed is ok. But that loop will be executed within another block which will be called for many times so it takes quite a long time to find all the sum. I wonder if there is any way to boost it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed that you should use a 3d matrix instead of cell.

What does sum of product remind you of?  Dot product.  What does a series of dot products remind you of?  vector-matrix multiply.  So what you want to do is reshape your data so that each column of your matrix is one unwrapped A{k}, and your B row-vector is your unwrapped B matrix.  In other words, the fact that A and B are 2D is irrelevant to your computation.

If you convert A to `A(:,:,k) = A{k}` as recommended, then:

```
vec = B(:).';
mtx = reshape(A, size(A,1)*size(A,2), size(A,3));
AllSum = vec*mtx;
```

Comment: Hi Peter, I try this code on rand matrices, it is pretty fast. But I just forget something that I didn't mention in my question (sorry for that) ... actually, A{k} is huge but sparse matrices, so if we make it as a 3D one, there will be too much zeros and in turns will lower the efficiency quite a lot eventually.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case, you can calculate the sum of all `A` matrixes first, then multiply by `B`. Instead of defining `A` as cell array, define them as one 3d array: (I agree on this one with @SeçkinSavaşçı)

```
A(:,:,i) = ...
```

Instead of:

```
A{i} = ...
```

Then, sum and multiply by `B`:

```
result = sum(A,3).* B;
```

Comment: i think the last code snippet is not doing the thing that we wanted. It first sums A then multiplies with B. We need to multiply(element wise) a part of A with B, then get the element sum of this result.

Comment: @SeçkinSavaşçı, Please correct me if I am wrong, (a1 + a2 + a3) * B is the same as a1 * b + a2 * b + a3 * b

Comment: You are right, thanks for enlightening me. But he stores different results for every k in the array, there is no cumulative result, as far as I understand.Other words, his result gives us 1000 elements, while your result gives 100x100

Comment: @SeçkinSavaşçı, I think that the OP meant to calculate single sum - check out his sentence - "return the total sum of all resulting elements". You are right in that the code snippet does what you say, but I guessed what he really wants.